# Problems with a field autocomplete material mui in stepper formik form

Tags: material-ui, autocomplete, formik

I am using a material ui autocomplete field in a Formik form, the form is part of a step form and my problem is that I cannot retrieve the value of the autocomplete field that has been selected by the user when I go back and forth through the form steps . Next I expose the piece of code that I have implemented and that has such a reported problem. Thank you all for the help you can provide.

```
 <Autocomplete
            defaultValue= {obrasoc.find((os) => os.nom_os == field.value)}
            options={obrasoc}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.nom_os}
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.nom_os === value.nom_os}
            renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                    {...params}
                    label='Obra Social'
                    variant="standard"
                    error={meta.touched && meta.error && true}
                    helperText={_renderHelperText()}
                />
            )}
            onChange={(e, value) => {
                console.log('onchange', value);
                fieldHelpers.setValue(value.nom_os)
            }}
        />
```

Comment: can you share the enough code to understand the problem or create an [example codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-mui-v5-forked-ykdjob?file=/src/App.js) ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the issue, only i had to replace the line ***label='Obra Social'*** with this  ***label= {field.value ? field.value : 'Obra Social'}*** and now i can surf over differents steps of form and the field in question remember the user input.